# Array cannot be assigned to Generic Reference

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Test {

    class Genric<C extends Clazz> {
        C[] s;

        public Genric() {
            this.s = new SubClazz[3];
        }
    }

    class Clazz {

    }

    class SubClazz extends Clazz {

    }
}
```

The code gives an error at `this.s = new SubClazz[3];` saying `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Test.Clazz[] to C[]`. Why does this error occur? How to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if `C` is bound to `SomeOtherSubClazz` for example, you would be doing

```
SomeOtherSubClazz[] s = new SubClazz[3];
```

which is analogous to:

```
Integer[] s = new Double[3];  // Integer and Double are both Numbers
```

Which obviously isn't type safe.

How to solve this obviously depends on what you want to do. Perhaps you can follow the approach suggested here: [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: I think I got the question wrong the first time. I edited the question. Can you help me out?

Comment: Guess the answer is the same. I will look into it. Thanks